# How to point eureka client to eureka server deployed in diffrent IP address not in localhost

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

i have an issue that i have a spring boot eureka server running on server with URL *http://192.168.3.177:8761/eureka*. Now i have eureka client(some service) running on other IP address i.e. *192.168.1.123*. But now the issue is when the eureka client starting it is taking eureka server IP as *localhost:8761/eureka* and giving connection refused exception.if i run the eureka client application in same server where the eureka server is running it is working as expected.

following is my eureka client configuration in application.properties

```
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://192.168.3.174:8761/eureka
```

My eureka client application

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients("com.samsan.currencyconversionservice")
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class CurrencyConversionServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CurrencyConversionServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And i am using ribbon to connect to the eureka server to fetch the service

```java
@Component
@FeignClient(name="currency-exchange-service")
@RibbonClient(name="currency-exchange-service")
public interface CurrencyExchangeService {

    @GetMapping("/currency-exchange/from/{from}/to/{to}")
    public CurrencyConversionBean getExchangeValue(@PathVariable("from") String from, @PathVariable("to") String to);

}
```

Please help me how to resolve this?

Comment: as far as I remember, property name should be `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone` isn't it?

Comment: I guess both spellings could be acceptable but that's could be easy checked in IntelyJ IDEA by clicking on property with Ctrl hold. I use `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone` and it works.

Comment: Yes it is working now with eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone .Thanks pvpkiran and alexery